# React Native Link for React Native .60 +

Tags: android, ios, react-native, npm-scripts, react-native-linking

This is still something that is required, I see this message all the time, but it's completely invalid from what I have experienced. Almost every package I work with, I still have to run the react-native link.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what's up with this? Is it just particular packages, or why do I still need to run react-native link all the time, when it tells me I shouldn't run it. I mean, it's really just adding it to the pod file for iOS and gradle for Android.

Anyone else experiencing this?

To show this further, look at this, just ran the npm install for lottie, it will not work unless I run the link, should I add to my pod file manually? I don't get why React Native (Facebook) team is saying that it's no longer required, out of our team of 4 people, we have had it required always.

[image]

Comment: The packages that are mentioned in the terminal will be automatically linked to the `react-native`, so it's a message that says these packages are automatically linked. So, unlink those packages manually.

Comment: lol, The point is, if they're autolinked, why did I have to run the react-native link ?? If I don't the app will not run, I am on a dev team and we have all noticed this. That the autolink is not true. Unless we are missing something, maybe a config file or something? Almost every package, we have to run the ```react-native link {PACKAGE NAME}``` then we see these messages, and yes we can manually unlink, but that's not the point. 

It's odd why do we have to run link to just run unlink??

Comment: Updated @Thinker with screenshot showing it requires to run the react-native link for lottie, (shrug) looks like react-native link is still required based on what I see.

Comment: looks to me like u just need to use "link" on ios side using pod, react-native link command handles that setup for u in a different way that's why it's working for u after u used react native link, but the message seems to only care for u to use pod, which is a requirement still based on https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md#autolinking, not necessarily the whole 'react-native link' command which includes android side

Comment: Can you confirm this project was initially using react native 0.60+. I haven't manually linked a package in a long time now. Almost every package mentioned in your post support auto link and it never failed for me.

Comment: Are you upgraded this project to 0.60 or started after the 0.60?

Answer (score 2):

Starting with version 0.60 React Native provides auto-linking.

That means if a library supports auto-linking all you have to do is install the library with `yarn` or `npm`, run `pod install` in the ios folder and build.

```
# install
yarn add <the-library-name>
cd ios && pod install && cd .. # CocoaPods on iOS needs this extra step
# run
yarn react-native run-ios
yarn react-native run-android
```

By example https://github.com/react-native-geolocation/react-native-geolocation supports auto-linking and you don't need it in the `Podfile.` (unless you have a very old version of it).

In your case all the libraries listed in the print-screen as manually linked were added manually using `react-native link <libraryName>` or manually inside the Podfile or using a reference to a `.xcodeproj` file inside Xcode.

**To remove those errors:**

**Make sure you have a library version that supports auto-linking and run `react-native unlink <libraryname>` and `pod install`**

**Note**: **to avoid some problems I found that sometimes its better to remove the `podfile.lock` and generate a new one with the `pod install`**

**If that doesn't work follow the steps from below:**

**1) Remove the lines in Podfile associated with those libraries** (unless the library version that you have doesn't support auto-linking, in that case you should just run use manual linking as mentioned in the library docs).

You can check how a Podfile looks for a specific RN version by taking a look in the RN upgrade helper:

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.59.5&to=0.63.3

**2) You should not need now manual references in Xcode for libraries that support auto-linking** (unless the library requires some special step mentioned in its docs).

This is how manual linking used to be done:

[image]

Source and more info here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking-libraries-ios

For the libraries that support auto-linking to avoid any errors you could remove the references(`.xcodeproj` and others) in Xcode associated with them (unless the associated library requires the modifications in Xcode)

Sources and some useful links:

https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md

https://medium.com/@srbkrishnan/react-native-auto-linking-on-android-65a850bb9ed9

Additional notes about the RN upgrade:
I found that if there are too many things to modify in my `project.pbxproj` file at an upgrade, it was easier for me to start with a brand new `project.pbxproj` file taken directly from the RN upgrade helper. Then I replaced `RnDiffApp` with `MyProjectName` in that file and added the library modifications that I needed in Xcode one by one.

Comment: I have never ever had one package work with auto linking - NEVER! I have to always run react-native link {package-name}. To this day, on React Native 63 and still having to run the react-native link, or I get the "Did you forget to run pod install", no I just ran it.. Auto linking DOES NOT WORK. Tried on 3 computers, same thing. I want video of it working.

Comment: Creating a demo for a library from the printscreen attached to the question: `react-native init svgDemo`, `cd svgDemo`, `yarn add react-native-svg`, `cd ios`, `pod install`, import it in `App.js`, use it in render function to render a basic circle, `react-native run-ios` and you will be surprised that it works. You can check `Podfile` and `package.json` after that. Tested 5 mins ago

Comment: The test from my previous comment was done using RN 0.63

Answer (score 0):

You will not need to link more libs anymore you just have to upgrade your React-native module and make sure you are also using the latest Xcode and all issues will be gone.
thanks.